# "docker-compose up -d" in this docker command what does "-d" do

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker Command> docker-compose up -d 
in this docker command what does

> -d

do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"d" stands for detach, meaning it will run in the background.

Just use `docker-compose up --help` to see the options and their definition.